# Who found out about galaxies?

Tags: astronomy

As the world developed new technology, astronomers discovered more celestial bodies, such as asteroids and black holes and such. Galaxies were probably discovered long ago before these modern telescopes came along. Even with the lack of technology, someone has discovered about the galaxies. Who and how did he/she find out about the galaxies' existance?

Comment: Here's [a brief overview](http://earthguide.ucsd.edu/virtualmuseum/ita/04_1.shtml) answering the question. The internet is rife with similar short stories.

Comment: Wikipedia gives a history survey http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy#Observation_history

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is easily found on the Internet.

Comment: As a protest against the causeless destruction, I voted this question up.